# Convert pandas set_value to at[]

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a code as

```
df.set_value(index, 'review_category', 'No_Reviews')
```

And its give me warning as below:

```
FutureWarning: set_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use .at[] or .iat[] accessors instead
```

I tried converting this code as below:

```
df.at[index, 'review_category'] = 'No_Reviews'
```

Now I am receiving the below error:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'review_category'
```

Comment: What is `df.columns.tolist()` ?

Comment: could you clarify the question by maybe showing the `df.columns` in your dataset, with also 'df.head()'?

Comment: Sorry but cant show the dataframe

Comment: Seems, there is no column with name 'review_category' in df..

Answer (score 1):

- df.loc gets rows (or columns) with particular labels from the index.
- df.iloc gets rows (or columns) at particular positions in the index
  (so it only takes integers).

In your example, assuming your index to be starting from 0,1,2... and so on, you can do it with

```
    df.iloc[index]['review_category'] = 'No_Reviews'
```

Comment: Thanks but its giving a warning: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Use `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` to avoid warnings from chained assignements. The warning arises because the selection returns a copy and not the original dataframe.